# Spring Security CORS Issue: "OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/ 403 ()"

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, cors, angular-cli

I've been working on a project using spring + spring security on my backend and have recently run into an issue with cors specifically:

[image: The first two lines you can see successful api call output, following that chrome attempts to send http request with an options header to my rest service.]

The first two lines you can see **successful api call output**, following that chrome attempts to send a Http request with an options header to my rest service.

---

***My question is what could potentially be the source of this issue?***

---

My front end in dev uses the angular CLI client, I havent had any issues with CORS until i created a custom filter for spring security hence adding my `WebConfigurerAdapter` config. Happy to supply additional code if required. However I don't think its related to that as I've removed the filter and the same issue occurs.

Tested in chrome, firefox and ubuntu browser same issue occurs.

**Angular CLI is successfully proxying calls to '/api/[blah]'**
[image: Angular CLI is Proxying my rest service]

Here's my proxy config, i've tried just matching on everything but that makes no difference.

```
{
"/api/*": {
  "target": "http://localhost:8080",
  "secure": false,
  "logLevel": "debug",
  "changeOrigin": true
}
```

}

`WebSecurityAdapter` Config

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/index.html",  "/api/registration", "/api/authenticate",
                    "/api/isAuthenticated", "/api/validateCaptcha", "/console", "/api/loginRecaptchaRequired", "/api/login", "/")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(
                    authenticationFilter(),
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/api/logout")
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
            .and()
            .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), SessionManagementFilter.class);

}
```

Request headers:
[image]

Comment: You appear to be missing the allow-origin header, so no origins can use CORS. [Info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

Comment: Backend, I would work out which domains should be able to make CORS requests, and whitelist them here, unless you want to make it public, then use `*`

Comment: Thanks, using this to add cors: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/cors.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Why your code wasn't working

You are missing the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, so that no site is allowed to make CORS requests to your site

## Fixes

You can either:

- Make the requests from the same origin
- Use spring security to add the header to the responses
- Manually add the header

## What origins to allow

The header is either a whitelist of origins to allow, or it can be `*` to allow any origin to send requests.

## Does this stop all requests except whitelisted ones

This only protects in browsers, mallicious software can still make requests to any endpoint without having to comply with CORS.

Comment: Thanks :) the one thing i find strange is that I've been using the same setup for a while now but haven't had to add cors, ideally id like to set it up so that i don't have to allow cors so that there's no way cors is accidentally added to prod. additionally with allowing localhost:4200 couldn't an attacker just proxy themselves to appear as that site?

Comment: It is more to prevent cookies being sent with requests, as the attacker wouldn't be able to make requests to the API as a logged in user, even if they proxied access to the API.